# SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Audit log

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, auditing

Can I read from audit log, how many times item has been clicked?
I know that I can do it using Server edition, but what about Foundation?

What I have done: Central Administration, I enabled Secure Store Service / "Audit log enabled"

[image]

I also installed https://auditlogsp.codeplex.com/ and I checked logs.
However, it seems that Foundation do not save item openings?

[image]

I can read same log of course from database: WSS_Content.AuditData

My idea is get all items, which users have clicked most. Can anyone confirm, whether this possible?

I also tried using custom code, but some reason it return 0:

```
class MostViewedItems
{

public DataTable table = new DataTable();

public SPSite siteUrl;

public DataTable GetRecentlyViewedReports()
{
    try
    {
        table.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(Guid));
        table.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("ItemCount", typeof(int));

        siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site;
        string url = siteUrl.Url;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
                {
                    getRecentAuditlog(web, "Documents");
                    web.Dispose();
                }
            }
        });
        // TODO
    }
}

public void getRecentAuditlog(SPWeb web, string lst)
    {
        try
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(lst);
            if (list != null)
            {
                SPAuditQuery spQuery = new SPAuditQuery(web.Site);
                spQuery.RestrictToList(list);
                spQuery.RestrictToUser(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID);
                spQuery.AddEventRestriction(SPAuditEventType.View);
                spQuery.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30));
                spQuery.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
                SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = web.Site.Audit.GetEntries(spQuery);

                // auditCol returns 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled auditing for the Secure Store Service and that only enables auditing for operations on the Secure Store Service Application.

You have to enable auditing for the site collection where your list resides.

As per the following comparison chart auditing is not included in SharePoint Foundation 2013, at least not using the UI.

[SP 2013 version comparison chart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx)

It can be enabled with PowerShell though:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://site_URL 
$site.Audit.AuditFlags = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Update #or any other mask type
$site.Audit.Update()
```

[Source](http://sharepointdragons.com/2012/05/08/auditing-in-sharepoint-foundation/)

For SP 2013 Standard or Enterprise:

Go to Site Actions –> Site Settings –> Site Collection Administration –> Site Collection audit settings

Comment: What about these two: http://goo.gl/G6JgLJ and http://goo.gl/GGXMvt ? Or is it the same thing? Secure Store Service Application?

Comment: I haven't tried the second link. Its worth a try. Maybe MSFT's comperison chart is only for what's available with UI. If you have already done that then check the content database. With an SQL query check the entries in AuditData table.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking also, that audit is missing only UI side. 
However, I can see easily what document have been added, modified or removed. But I cannot see document what users have opened. Or does I miss something? Because, it records View Events. I have tried find answer, what Foundation audit log saves, but no luck.
I'm hoping that someone knows here.

Comment: Ok, that means auditing is working. Make sure that the flag for view events is set. Check [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaudit.auditflags.aspx)

Comment: And one more issue I've seen users reporting lately that opening a document as read only is not registered as View event but opening for editing and closing without editing/saving registers the view event. Check that too.

Comment: Yes, audit log works! Some reason it updates documents to audit log very slowly. It can take 5min, before it shows up in audit log. It updates audit log much faster, if it's not library document, what you have uploaded. But yes, SharePoint Foundation 2013 supports audit log.

Comment: I updated the answer with your reference. It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions above, I was able to turn on auditing for one of my sites, but queries can only be run through PowerShell, on Foundation there is no GUI audit option (as mentioned above as well). Also, in my case the PowerShell script/commands required the farm account to run it, I kept getting an "Access denied" error when I was running it from my account (a local admin on the SharePoint box). I used:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://site_URL
$site.Audit.AuditFlags = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Update -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Delete
$site.Audit.Update()
```

Then I used this command to pull site updates or deletes:
    $site.Audit.GetEntries()