# No Audit logs in sharepoint 2013

Tags: auditing, log

i'm pretty new to sharepoint, i installed it on a server 2012, Microsoft Sharepoint foundation 2013. Recently i wanted to see some audit logs, at my suprise i saw that they simple don't exist. In some posts here a read i have to enable them in site collection features --> enable reporting (i also don't have this checkbox to activate).
On this picture you can see what i have under Site Collection Administration

[image: site]

On this one is all i have on site collection features
[image: features]

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Site Collection Audit logging isn't a feature you active. But because you're using SharePoint Foundation, there is no UI to enable, disable, or export the Site Collection Audit log. You can work with the `SPAudit` API. A good example of this is available on a previous SP:SE post, [SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Audit log](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90248/sharepoint-foundation-2013-audit-log).